# Find and divide number in xml

Tags: python, xml, divide

i have an xml (skin) file with the X and Y cordinates.
I have to divide (for 1.5) all the numbers inside the tags:

```
position = "x, x" or size = "x, x"
```

example:

```
position = "1700,90" size = "125,125"
```

becomes:

```
position = "1113,60" size = "83,83"
```

The file is very large I can not make 1 to 1. I need a script (.sh or .py), I created something but unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you be more concrete what is wrong(what errors you get) with what you have tried? Also put code that you came up with.

Comment: I tried to write something in python but the code is complicated and I did not get anything concrete.

Comment: But still you need to make it more readable, SO community is passionate about helping, but making work for you won't make you any good(in understanding the problem). So i suggest you to try your best and if you got any errors, put them here as well as code.

Answer (score 0):

if file is very big, better is to use [SAX xml parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.html?highlight=sax#module-xml.sax), or http://lxml.de which uses libxml2 (very fast parser). I recommend SAX because you don't need DOM, only to find specific tag and change its attributes (?). Script will be like filter. Another option is to use `grep` but `grep` expression may be complex (I don't know how looks your XML file).

Comment: Is not very big.
I mean it's great to do this hand by dividing one by one all the numbers